# Rules in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Dialogflow documentation mentions that agents can be set in two modes, Hybrid(Rule-base and ML) and ML Only. How do we set up rules in Dialogflow? Can't find any documentation for this. Or is it only through training phrases? For example I want to set a rule that says any utterance that starts with 'XYZ' should be matched against Intent A.

I've tried marking 'XYZ' as an entity at the beginning of the training phrases in Intent A hoping that all such utterances are matched with this intent, however that does not seem to be happening.

'XYZ needs some goods to be transferred to location 23'

I expect such utterances to be matched against Intent A but that doesn't happen always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule based agent will match only those request which will match the training phrases as it is (or maybe it will match lemma values also).

It will match the sentence and extract the parameters as well if you have annotated the parameters in the training phrase.

But it will not match the variant of the sentence.

[image: rule-1]
[image: rule-2]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! So for the example 'XYZ needs some goods to be transferred to location 23', if I mark "needs some goods to be transferred to location 23" as the parameter then the intent is matched for all utterances starting with 'XYZ'.

Comment: @AiyappaHirepirates yes, and it is working as expected as well. please refer to the screenshots i attached.